# How to set The push button should only work when two line edit input widgets contain text

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have created two line Edit input widgets and one push button.
I need to set The push button should only work when two line edits contain text.
I need to set two line edit input widgets as mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect the `QLineEdit.textEdited` signal to a function to check if all the required fields contain text, and enable/disable the button accordingly. Here is an example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.f1 = QLineEdit()
        self.f1.textEdited.connect(self.check_input)
        self.f2 = QLineEdit()
        self.f2.textEdited.connect(self.check_input)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Enter')
        self.btn.setDisabled(True)

        form = QFormLayout(self)
        form.addRow('Field 1', self.f1)
        form.addRow('Field 2', self.f2)
        form.addRow(self.btn)

    def check_input(self):
        if self.f1.text() and self.f2.text():
            self.btn.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.btn.setDisabled(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```